# Deploying LabVIEW VI on web page

Tags: labview

I have created a VI consisting of table and file handling. I have tried using LabVIEW NXG, but some features of LabVIEW are not supported in NXG. I have also tried using Web Publisher tool of LabVIEW, but it only works in Internet Explorer, not on Chrome. Could anyone help me host my LabVIEW VI on web?

Comment: If you need support for Chrome then your best option is probably to persevere with NXG, for the reasons described at https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019LCKSA2&l=en-GB. What is NXG missing that you require? Have you looked at any workarounds ahead of those features becoming available in NXG?

Comment: nxg is missing prompt vis and request for vi file. is there anyway to get them in nxg?